# Using UrlConnection instead of HttpClient with JSONArray

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Now I am using HttpClient which is deprecated! :-(
So I would like to use HttpUrlConnection..
Here is my code:

```
public JSONArray GetDetails(int ID){



        // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
        // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

        try
        {

           DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(StaticVariables.url_for_details + ID);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            // Signals error in http protocol
            e.printStackTrace();

            //Log Errors Here



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        if (httpEntity != null) {
            try {
                String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Can someone help me to use HttpUrlConnection instead of the HttpClient so I can use jsonarray furthermore?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Or what in particular you don't understand / know that prevents you from using HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: I don't know in which way I have to use HttpUrlConnection in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 public void getData(){

        try {
                  URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL");
                  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                  String readStream = readStream(con.getInputStream());

                  System.out.println(readStream);

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(readStream);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            String age=object.getString("age");
        }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }


}
             private String readStream(InputStream in) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));) {

                  String nextLine = "";
                  while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(nextLine);
                  }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return sb.toString();
              }
```

For more reference check this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: ok now I have all data from the internet but now I want to have single items like : jsonArray.get("name") and you become only the name

Comment: what is your json, post it here

Comment: [{"uid":"112","unique_id":"55f44cbe8899e0.90440511","name":"aa","full_name":"tt","email":"aa@gmail.com","age":"18","about_the_customer":"o","encrypted_password":"+bla","salt":"bla","created_at":"2015-09-12 18:03:10","updated_at":null,"imageName":"bla.jpg"}] and for example I want only to show the age in a textview or something else

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer? I can't comment this because the code has more characters than I can use here.

Comment: aren't you using the answer i have posted here? by the way you need to convert string builder to string in your code

Comment: your code hasn't worked for me.. I tried to implement yours

Comment: code works, you are just not using it in the right way, i have edited answer for your convenience now, please mark as correct if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static String getData(String uri) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));


            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String age = jsonObject.getString("age");
                Log.e("age", " is" + age);
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my method now but this with the JSONArray won't work...
The Log says:
org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class java.lang.StringBuilder